# Como usar Reporting Services 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

Que tal comunidad Alguien sabe oh a utilizado SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 que me pueda resolver una duda se los agradeceria
Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este reporte el cual se presenta mediante el filtro de folio que se observa este filtro es de opcion multiple puedo seleccionar varios folios y ver reflejados en el reporte, pero lo que deseo yo esque por cada folio que se seleccione, me muestre la informacion del reporte en diferente pagina,donde se oberva 1 de 1 en el primero folio y 2 de 2 en el segundo y no los gunte todos en uno mismo folio, Creen que sea posible

Comment: ¿Y cual sería exactamente la duda? ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar exactamente la dudaque mencionas?

Comment: Listo espero sea mas comprencible